# Multiple dex files define error in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

im a begginer in android studio and im trying to perform a database sync with mysql and a android database. after following a guide (it makes no mention to gradle stuff however so im having to improvise) im left with the bellow error
After searching i was told its probably my dependencies but i haven't had much look so far

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
}
```

my library in the .idea folder look like this

```
libraries

android_async_http_1_4_4.xml
android_support_v4.xml
appcompat_v7_21_0_3.xml
gson_2_2_2.xml
support_annotations_21_0_3.xml
support_v4_21_0_3.xml
```

this is the error i got

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Developer Tools/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Volumes/Untitled/You copy/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Volumes/Untitled/You copy/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

thank you for any help you can offer me

Comment: i guess android_support_v4 libraries are conflicting

Comment: @Exobyte please try me answer.

Comment: i wont be able to try it out till tommorrow morning when i use the collage computers as i get the bellow on when trying to use my laptop, updating java dint help.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: @Exobyte Make sure you have the latest Android SDK and support library packages.

Comment: As far as i can tell i do have thouse, opened up sdk manager, clicked update on everything on 4.4.2 as thats what im using, got all the tools and android support library/repository.

Comment: Always use the latest SDK.

Comment: Got it to work, both problems were casued by the same thing, thank you very mutch for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

With `Gradle` dependencies, `AppCompatv7` also brings in `Supportv4`. So, simply remove `Supportv4` `.jar` because you are accidentally adding it twice.

### Your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') // <-- remove jar
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
}
```

### Should be:

I also upgraded your `.jars` into `Gradle` dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' // <-- upgraded
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' // <-- upgraded to gradle dependency
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4' // <-- upgraded to gradle dependency
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle knows how to resolve dependency conflicts. You can read about that here : https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html .

So the error is not because `appcompat` clashes with `support-v4`.

It looks like you're referencing twice, libraries from your `libs` folder.

Either use:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar') }
```

or:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' 
}
```

However, my recommendation is to also reference `support-v4`, `gson` and `android-async` as you reference `appcompat-v7.`